# django-admin pointing outside virtualenv

Tags: django, python-3.x, virtualenvwrapper

I've initialised a virtual environment using the virtualenvwrapper command `mkvirtualenv -a <path to project> django_project`.

I then installed django with `pip install django`. But then if i try to use `django-admin` i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 7, in <module>
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Now `pip list` gives me

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
Django     2.1.3
pip        18.1
pytz       2018.7
setuptools 40.6.2
wheel      0.32.3
```

`python -m django --version` gives

```
2.1.3
```

If I run `which python` it correctly points to my virtualenv, however `which django-admin` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin/django-admin
```

I'd think that it should point to my venv. Why would it point to a global django admin? How do I fix it so that it'll work for my future virtual environments?

I'm on MacOS using zsh and python 3.7.0.

Thank you!

Edit: Mistake in a command

Edit: I realised I don't have a system-wide installation of Django and so the `django-admin` and `django-admin.py` files in my `/usr/local/bin` must've been leftovers from an earlier installation. Hence I deleted them and that solved the problem. Without any further `django-admin` inside the venv point to the correct django installation (inside the venv).

However, I would still like to know why the command didn't point to the Django installed in the venv in the first place?

Comment: Jus checked my `$PATH` inside the venv, and it correctly points to the venv as the first directory. In the `env/bin` there is a django-admin with the shebang line correctly pointing to the venv...

Answer (score 2):

So Django has been installed at system level, while you verified that `python` command refer to your virtual environment. I bet this is an issue with `pip`. You may check that it is under `<path to project>/bin` and is correctly used when you perform

```
(django_project) $ pip install django
```

Try to run

```
which pip
```

with your venv enabled and disabled to see what pip is used in each case

Comment: Thank you Antwane. I don't think django was installed system-wide this time around. `which pip` correctly points to the venv, while active and to the system while not active. I can also see that django is installed in the venv/bin folder.

Comment: In such case, you have to understand why django-admin executable was copied into /usr/local/bin/django-admin. It may have been installed from OS package manager (previous installation ?). Can you try to `pip uninstall django` and check the list of files about to be deleted to see if this command try to modify something at system level ? Also, which user own `/usr/local/bin/django-admin` ?

Comment: As I write in my latest edit, I think the django-admin executables in `/usr/local/bin/` are leftovers from a previous installation, as you write. I deleted them and it solved the problem for me. I can't see the owner as I have deleted them, but I'm quite sure it would have been me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after reboot it solved the issue for me.

Don't forget to check if the executable `django-admin` is inside the virtualenv's `bin` folder:

```bash
~/Documents/Django_python/django/bin $ ls
activate                deactivate.nu           pip3.10                 wheel
activate.fish           *django-admin*          python                  wheel3
activate.nu             pip                     python3                 wheel3.10
activate.ps1            pip3                    python3.10              wheel-3.10activate.csh
activate_this.py        pip-3.10                sqlformat
```

(*) Highlight mine.